# Using asynchronous attribute in derived types

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

In Fortran2003 program, I want to create a derived type that includes an allocatable array with `asynchronous` attribute:

```
module async_in_type
  type async_array
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable, asynchronous :: a
  end type async_array
end module async_in_type
```

When I try to compile the code above with GCC, I get the following error message:

```
$ gfortran -c -Wall -Wextra async_in_type.F90
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.10.0 20140718 (experimental)
async_in_type.F90:3.52:

    integer, dimension(:), allocatable, asynchronous :: a
                                                1
Error: Attribute at (1) is not allowed in a TYPE definition
```

With NAG Fortran the message is similar:

```
$ nagfor -c async_in_type.F90 
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 6.0(Hibiya)
Product NPL6A60NA for x86-64 Linux
Error: async_in_type.F90, line 3: Syntax error
       detected at ,@ASYNCHRONOUS
[NAG Fortran Compiler pass 1 error termination, 1 error]
```

What is the reason for such restriction? Is it possible to overcome this restriction?

Comment: Not many people are subscribed to the fortran2003 tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler message is exact and very clear, let me repeat it:

```
Error: Attribute at (1) is not allowed in a TYPE definition
```

So it simply isn't allowed by the standard.

You must put the `asynchronous` attribute to the variables of type `async_in_type`.

```
type(async_in_type), asynchronous :: x
```

Comment: Putting 'asynchronous' attribute to the variables of type 'async_in_type' does not change the semantics, do it? Can I use 'x%a' in the context that requires 'asynchronous' attribute?

Comment: Yes, you can use it, it is valid for all components.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add support to [Vladimir F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565669) with references (and some speculation).  Yes, the (Fortran 2008) standard does not allow this use of the `asynchronous` attribute.

For components of a derived type, look at 4.5.4.1 where the allowed attributes for a component are given (R437).  `asynchronous` is just not listed (`dimension` and `allocatable` of the question are).

The `asynchronous` attribute is described in 5.3.4

> An entity with the ASYNCHRONOUS attribute is a variable that may be subject to asynchronous input/output.

This partly motivates the restriction: the defined component is not in itself a variable.  Perhaps what you want to say with placing the attribute in the definition is that all variables of this type have components with that attribute.

As Vladimir F says, the attribute is specified (perhaps even implicitly - see 9.6.2.5 - so this explicit confirmation may not be too troublesome a burden) on the derived type object.  Even if it weren't, by say

```
asynchronous :: x%a ! Using Vladimir F's terminology
```

then 5.3.4 also says that the base object of the variable with that attribute shall also have that attribute.  We further know that sub-objects of an object with that attribute have the attribute - so "siblings" of an asynchronous component must also be asynchronous.

If we come to "why can't we have some components with the attribute and some without?" then we must speculate, but there's at least evidence presented here that the authors of the standard thought about that possibility before rejecting it.

Finally, R427 (in 4.5.2.1) rules out the case `type, asynchronous :: async_array`

Comment: If you want to know why this is not allowed, the best forum to ask would probably be comp.lang.fortran , where you will find many Fortran standard comittee members.